# How to add a marker to canvas with a position that recalculates when zooming in or out

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, nuxt.js

I am loading a map which can be dragged and zoomed in and out with HTML5 canvas. This works perfect. I can also place a marker i.e. at pixel 500x 600y. But when I zoom the map in or out, the pixels obviously change and the 500x and 600y are not correct anymore.  Therefore the marker will shift a little bit and its position is not correct anymore.

If I would zoom out once, and console log the map size which originally was 4097 x 2142 it now is 3687.3 x 1927.8. I think this also means that the original marker position of [500, 500] has to be recalculated to fix my issue... but I have no clue how to.

Been trying for days now to figure out how to fix this but I have no clue... can anyone please help me out on how to solve this matter?

I am using Vue (Nuxt) and HTML5 canvas. I can provide a zip with my project if that helps ;)

Below is the most important piece of code I recon:

```
// Initial position when the map is loaded (map size 4097x2142)
ICO_POS.value = [500, 500] // Icon will be displayed at 500x 6000y

// This function will check if we zoomed in or out
const zoom = (e) => {
  if (e.wheelDelta > 0) {
    zoomIn()
  } else {
    zoomOut()
  }
}

// Zoom in function
const zoomIn = (e) => {
  if (DEFAULT_ZOOM.value < MAX_ZOOM) {
    DEFAULT_ZOOM.value += ZOOM_STEP
  }
}

// Zoom out function
const zoomOut = (e) => {
  if (DEFAULT_ZOOM.value > MIN_ZOOM) {
    DEFAULT_ZOOM.value -= ZOOM_STEP
  }
}

// This function will draw the map and icons
const drawImage = () => {
    // Draw the map
    const w = image.width * DEFAULT_ZOOM.value
    const h = image.height * DEFAULT_ZOOM.value
    const x = DRAW_POS.value[0] - (w / 2)
    const y = DRAW_POS.value[1] - (h / 2)
    context.drawImage(image, x, y, w, h)
    
    // Draw the icon
    const w2 = (image2.width * 3) * DEFAULT_ZOOM.value
    const h2 = (image2.height * 3) * DEFAULT_ZOOM.value
    const x2 = ICO_POS.value[0] - (w2 / 2)
    const y2 = ICO_POS.value[1] - (h2 / 2)
    context.drawImage(image2, x2, y2, w2, h2)
}
```

Comment: Usually, we use a map and place markers on it (coordinates on a 2D plan), resizing should be done in a responsive way to keep the boundaries in a bigger/smaller form factor. If you work only with a canvas, you'll have to deal with pixels and rounding it/making computations will only be approximate. Hence, I do recommend switching to some 3rd party API or to have a corresponding X and Y coordinates into an object. It will be clean when you'll be resizing the whole thing.

Comment: You have a very good point there kissu! but in all honesty, I would not know where to start if I would want to refactor what I have currently. I am totally new to Canvas and it is really mind blowing to me. Unfortunately, I have to do it myself as I do not want to (can not) rely on a 3rd-party software/ API.

I will try to figure out and remake it with the suggestion(s) you gave me to have a better start. Meanwhile if anyone knows a solution... I am all ears :)

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, you'll have a lot of work (learning how to have geo coordinates is not easy because of the granularity/precision). If you want to have the ability to zoom while doing it yourself with a bitmap or a JS object replicating the map on a matrix, it will be wrong/non-precise at some point. I've done some Blender recently (same idea applies in your case IMO), and the idea of having some flat plane but still being able to zoom on it (while not killing the performance) is nearly impossible by yourself. Why cannot you use some open source API for this?

Comment: Oké... let me ask this then. What would be the best and most simple way to 1. Display a map (JPG image). And on top of that multiple markers (JPG image). And when I zoom in or pan, the markers should stay at the same spot on the base image (the map). Can that be done? and the reason I dont want to use 3rd party stuff is due to its size, the amount of stuff that I dont need and that I would like to learn it myself with minimal code ;)

Comment: Zooming on a map with markers cannot be done easily because it requires some scaling. Especially if your markers are JPG too. I'm not sure that every maps are heavy. Still, if you're trying to do it yourself it will not be performant either so yeah, rather just use a tool made for this purpose. So yeah, the simplest, most functional and best way is to use a map tool/library for this one (minimal code).

Comment: Oke, makes sense. Is there any library that you would recommend to use?

Comment: I've worked a bit with leaflet.js. You could probably google and found out more: https://opensource.com/life/15/11/getting-started-web-mapping Depends on what you want. I never did it myself so I cannot link an exact path for this.

Comment: Ahhh, I tried leaflet and this works great! I am just stuck at using my own map. I opened my png file in photoshop (4096 width) and used a Google maps tile maker script to make tiles which are now in a directory called tiles/x/y/z/image.png so to speak. But when I add it, they simply wont load. When I look in my inspector it tries to load files that do not exist  for example http://localhost:3000/images/maps/1/12/2052/2047.png. I am using Nuxt with https://github.com/schlunsen/nuxt-leaflet. Will try to figure it out and let the outcome know here. Thanks so much for your replies so far!

Comment: What's the error in the console?